# Format mysql timestamp to something meaningful

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, date-formatting

My database uses a TIMESTAMP column for each article which gets data written to it whenever an article is written to the database. This is done automatically by the database using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value for the column.

Unfortunately, the date appears as `2011-11-24 19:26:57` which is not ideal for - well - anything.

What I'd like to do is write it to my page in the same format as `Thu 24 Nov 2011 19:26:57`.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried looking to [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) php function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MySql builtin function to format date-time column

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_col, '%a %d %b %Y %k:%i:%s')
FROM your_table
```

Comment: I think you have swapped the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> which is not ideal for - well - anything.

You are wrong. It is indeed and exclusively ideal for the *sorting* dates.

And for the formatting both PHP and mysql has strtotime()+date() and DATE_FORMAT() respectively.

Also note that you may wish to change TIMESTMP to DATETIME format, as the former can be easily altered by accident and thus spoil whole database.

Comment: I had considered datetime format initially, but I was unable to set a default constraint on it. That's why I went with timestamp.

Comment: @Logan you can always set it manually, as well as other fields with INSERT - no need for the default value. Less defaults in your code - less unpredictable errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can use MySQL DATE_FORMAT function which formates the timestamp in a way you like see this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

take a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php This builds an array of a string representing a date, you can then format "your" date however you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the mysql function [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

e.g.  SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');

-> 'Sunday October 2009'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in either PHP or MySQL:

PHP code:

```
<php
    $formattedDate = strftime('%a %e %b %Y %T',strtotime($mysqlDate));
?>
```

MySQL code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%W %e %M &Y %T', date_col);
```

Info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a couple of options. One of them is to use [MySQL directly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

An example to match you need would be:

```
SELECT field1, field2, DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%a %e %b %Y %T') AS theDateFROM table;
```

Another option is to use the [date()](http://php.net/date) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) functions from PHP with the timestamp directly:

```
<?php echo date("D j M Y H:i:s", strtotime($datetime_from_database)); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is good for you

1

```
<?php date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); ?>
```

2

```
<?php date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>
```

1

Sat Sep 9 4:13:18 CDT 2006

2

September 9, 2006, 4:13 am